# Android build having drawable resources with the same name

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

My project has 2 different dependencies:

```
implementation ("com.example:aar:1.0.0")
implementation project(':project-example')
```

Both of them has a drawable resource with the same name `drawable-example.png` and `drawable-example.xml`. Following [the android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#dependency-order) I placed the `aar` dependency first, so it will get higher priority for merging.

For some reason, after the merge process, the drawable from the project overrides the drawable from the `aar`.

Comment: why not changing the name if your drawable?

Comment: I'm not sure that the link is valid for resources in dependencies too. I'm even not sure that this kind of behavior is documented. It's better just not to use same names.

Comment: I know that changing the name is the obvious easy answer, but let's assume that i cannot.